# Disable iPad / Safari context menu on long click

Tags: jquery, ios, css, ipad

I want to disable the "Open / Open in New Tab / Add to Reading List / Copy" context menu that is displayed when a link is pressed and held down using an iPad. The code below disables the context menus in browsers running on a PC or MacBook. On an iPad, however, the context menu continues to display.

Here is a test web page I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        $("a").contextmenu(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
        });     

    });
</script>
<style>
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href=#>Test Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`body { 
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}`

should do it

Comment: Steve, thanks for the answer. I have this in the html tag in the above code. I tried it in the body tag but that didn't help. Any other ideas?

Comment: seems this was a bug in webkit in iOS 8 betas, not sure why it still doesn't wrk: [link]https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136685